# android studio new project can't see src folder

Tags: android, android-studio

After the reinstall of android studio , I have created a new project: `MyapplicationProject`

**In Windows explorer** I see all the folders :

```
MyapplicationProject  
   \Myapplication 
      \libs  
      \src  
       ...
```

**In android studio** I don't see the src, libs, res folders!

See http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/3880/owi7.png

When I import an old project ==> ok.  I don't understand.  I don't find properties of the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest android studio, you can change the view. see the attached image[Change View from drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Ne4.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules

   1. Add Button (Green plus button) click -> New Module Select
   2. New Module window -> "Content root" change path button click to select "Project root file path"
   3. Apply to change save and "OK" button exit.

![enter image description here][1]

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/No6PS.png