# Don't see src folder after import libgdx project

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I created new project with libgdx and after importing it to Android Studio I do not see src folder libs and build. When I try run application at device, it shows this image on red background, so it works for sure. I tried create new module like in here : [android studio new project can't see src folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934676/android-studio-new-project-cant-see-src-folder) but could not make it working.

Comment: Did you use https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that I have these folders but can't see them at Android Studio.

Comment: If the setup succeeded... Please provide a `tree -d` or similar output of your project's directory's architecture

Comment: I m really new into android and programming at all, can you tell me how can I make output of directory architectoure?

Comment: `tree -d` is a linux command. You're saying no "src folder libs and build" exists, which should not be the case. Then, for the sake of us helping you, please post your project's architecture so that we can see what's wrong (a hierarchical view of folders if you prefer)...

Comment: http://gyazo.com/3a0f3ef6cffef0a03706b696327f742a this is project architecture in studio. Here it is real content:http://gyazo.com/a92823253c8136a4c4b878af73b45ed5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: attachment]

The blue "java" folder is your java source code (you can see your java package there).

That is just the way the IDE is displaying it to you.

Comment: Right, did not spotted that. But is there any problem that I do not see libs and build? Thank's for helping.

Comment: `libs` is maybe empty? Otherwise it will be at the same "level" as "manifest" or "src" i believe. I agree it's strange to see it layed out differently that it is from the filesystem, but that's just the IDE trying to make things more clear for you...

Comment: libs has 3 folders. But if it works (and it does :) ) i won't be looking for errors for now, thank you and good day